# Yahoo is not delivering emails

Tags: .net, email, sendmail, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

Im developing a web application in asp.net mvc (c#) that has a form and when the users submit the form, the data is sent to my boss. For sending the emails I use an smtp server of my own, that works great unless with yahoo accounts. :(

My boss has a yahoo email account, and for some reason yahoo doesnt deliver the emails that the webapp sends, not even on the spam inbox... I tested it with gmail and aim accounts and I receive the emails. Its just yahoo that for some reason is blocking my emails.

Do you know how can I solve this? I really need this to work with my boss yahoo account.

Thanks in advance.
Juan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because Yahoo treats these mails as spam. This article provides nice overview of what you should do to avoid that: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html